# Adding compression to .tar file?

Tags: compression, tar

I'm doing a backup scheme wherein we create an uncompressed .tar file, add any new or changed files to it for a week or two.  Now, at the end of this, is there an easy way to add compression to the .tar file so that we can start a new one?

Or do I just have to run a separate gzip command or similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do following `man gzip`!

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes guys.  I DID do research, and read thru the man, and there was no indication if this was possible..

Comment: are you saying `man gzip` doesn't cover how to gzip? seriously?

Comment: i didn't ASK about gzip, i asked about TAR functionality.  as in, if you'll read the actual question, can I use the TAR command to add compression to the TAR file after it's been created.

Comment: if you would `man tar` you'd see tar doesn't offer compression, `tar` originally was made for tapes, `gzip` can compress files such as `.tar`

Comment: You may want to look at `dar`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not adding compressed files directly? Anyway, `tar` can't compress single files later on, but just doing a `gzip file.tar` will have essentially the same effect... `mv` before, if you want to reuse the same file name for the next iteration right away...

Comment: If you mean why not create the tar originally with compression, it's because we want to be able to add/update it.  According to the man, you can't do that with a compressed tar.  So yeah, I'll have to just gzip it after Thanks!